# The number of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_{16}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to calculate the number of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_{16}$. But it is just that to calculate the number of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$. It is easy to calculate $Z_3$, but how to deal with $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  $\mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_{16} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{48}  $ and calculate the number of divisors of 48.

Comment: any theorem about that？ I mean the divisor and the subgroup

Comment: @JoeBerg Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: A finite cyclic subgroup has one *unique* subgroup of any order dividing the group's order.